# Variables not being found despite being defined?

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter

I am quite new to Python. I am trying to use tkinter for a basic program I am trying to set up. The initial code looks like this...

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Create the main window, Title, and the size
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My App')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.configure(bg='light blue')

# create a label for date and time
date_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=('Times New Roman', 14))
date_label.place(relx=0.11, rely=0.0, anchor='ne')
date_label.config(bg='light blue')

# Define a function to update date and time
def update_date_time():
    now = dt.now()
    current_time = now.strftime('%I:%M %p')
    current_date = now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    # Update the date and time label
    date_label.config(text=f"{current_date}\n{current_time}")

    # Schedule the function to be called after 1 second
    root.after(1000, update_date_time)

# Call the update_date_time function to start updating the label
update_date_time()

# Create entry widget for text
input = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=5)
input.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

# Start the main loop of the application
root.mainloop()
```

This works as intended, however I felt it looked messy, and I have essentially only added to widgets.
Thus (this is where my beginner will show) I wanted to organize my widgets by classes as such...

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Create the main window, Title, and the size
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My App')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.configure(bg='light blue')

class TimeWgt():
    # create a label for date and time
    date_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=('Times New Roman', 14))
    date_label.place(relx=0.11, rely=0.0, anchor='ne')
    date_label.config(bg='light blue')

    # Define a function to update date and time
    def update_date_time():
        now = dt.now()
        current_time = now.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        current_date = now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        # Update the date and time label
        date_label.config(text=f"{current_date}\n{current_time}")

        # Schedule the function to be called after 1 second
        root.after(1000, update_date_time)

    # Call the update_date_time function to start updating the label
    update_date_time()

# Create entry widget for text
input = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=5)
input.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

# Start the main loop of the application
root.mainloop()
```

After creating the class for TimeWgt, it says date_label is no longer defined, as nor my update_date_time function.

I am sure that this is just through my ignorance of code, and is a simple fix. Just wondering why it does this, and if there are suggestion on how to organize code better to make it more readable. Thank you!

P.S. was having issues with datetime.now module, which is why datetime is imported in the manner that it is.

Comment: Do you have any idea what a "class" is and how it is used in object oriented programming? Because that may be a point to start. At the very least, you need to put something in the parentheses: a parent of the class and `self` as first parameter of `update_date_time`.

Comment: You should probably research how to use class variables. Having said that, you'd be better off reworking this to use instance variables. Also, if you were to use an IDE with a Python linter (e.g., Visual Studio Code and Pylance) you would have been warned about your errors even before you tried running the code. There is also no apparent attempt to instantiate an instance of TimeWgt

Comment: My earlier comment is rude, isn't it? I didn't mean it to sound that way. I just got the impression you're using tools you don't fully understand. I honestly think doing some research might put you in the position to fix the code yourself.

Comment: @Friedrich all good. you are correct though. After some research I realized I probably shouldn't be using a class for solely one widget. As Pingu mentioned I will look into instanced variables.

Comment: The designers of tkinter are using one class per widget. There's nothing wrong with doing so if it makes for a cleaner design. I'd probably also use a class here. Pingu meant what the two answers implement, so there you have the abstract foundation to the actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful with class objects in OOP (Object Oriented programming). The structure of a class is the following:

```py
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self, ...):  # '...' --> implies the initial argument of the object
        ...  # here is the initial code

    def foo(self, params):  # Here is some method of the class
        ...

obj = ClassName(initial-params)  # initializate the object
obj.foo(params)  # call the method 'foo' from the object
```

I suggest to you to search more about when to use an object or whether use normal functions in your code. Anyways here is the nearest approach I could make to your code with not changing to much.

```py
class TimeWgt:

    def __init__(self, tk_obj, text, font):
        self.tk_obj = tk_obj  # save root object into a class variable
        # create a label for date and time
        self.date_label = tk.Label(tk_obj, text=text, font=font)
        self.date_label.place(relx=0.11, rely=0.0, anchor='ne')
        self.date_label.config(bg='light blue')

    # Define a function to update date and time
    def update_date_time(self):
        now = dt.now()
        current_time = now.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        current_date = now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        # Update the date and time label
        self.date_label.config(text=f"{current_date}\n{current_time}")

        # Schedule the function to be called after 1 second
        self.tk_obj.after(1000, self.update_date_time)



obj = TimeWgt(root, text='', font=('Times New Roman', 14))
# Call the update_date_time function to start updating the label
obj.update_date_time()
```

Answer (score 2):

Scope `date_label` to the instance of the `TimeWgt` class like so, using `self`:

```
class TimeWgt:
    def __init__(self, root):  # add the '__init__' method
        # this special method runs automatically whenever this class is instantiated!
        self.root = root
        # create a label for date and time
        self.date_label = tk.Label(self.root, text='', font=('Times New Roman', 14))
        self.date_label.place(relx=0.11, rely=0.0, anchor='ne')
        self.date_label.config(bg='light blue')

        # Call the update_date_time function to start updating the label
        self.update_date_time()

    # Define a function to update date and time
    def update_date_time(self):  # add 'self' to let this method access class attributes
        self.now = dt.now()
        self.current_time = self.now.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        self.current_date = self.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        # Update the date and time label
        self.date_label.config(text=f"{self.current_date}\n{self.current_time}")

        # Schedule the function to be called after 1 second
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_date_time)
```

`self` here refers to the current instance of the `TimeWgt` class

Then you'll want to instantiate the class like so

```
time_widget = TimeWgt(root)
```

where `root` is referring to `root = tk.Tk()` as you'vf defined globally

---

As an aside, the `datetime` import is correct! `from datetime import datetime` is importing the *class* called `datetime` from the *module* `datetime`. Per convention, the **class** should really be named `Datetime` (with an uppercase "D"), but alas...

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way.

Put the `Label` widget outside of class. This way you can be called `date_label` anywhere outside or inside class.

- Commented out line15 and 16.
- In line 29 put this `root.after(1000, update_date_time)` outside of
  function.

You' re ready to go.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Create the main window, Title, and the size
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My App')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.configure(bg='light blue')

date_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=('Times New Roman', 14))
date_label.place(relx=0.11, rely=0.0, anchor='ne')

class TimeWgt():
    # create a label for date and time
    #date_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=('Times New Roman', 14))
    #date_label.place(relx=0.11, rely=0.0, anchor='ne')
    date_label.config(bg='light blue')

    # Define a function to update date and time
    def update_date_time():
        now = dt.now()
        current_time = now.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        current_date = now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        # Update the date and time label
        date_label.config(text=f"{current_date}\n{current_time}")

        # Schedule the function to be called after 1 second
    root.after(1000, update_date_time)

    # Call the update_date_time function to start updating the label
    update_date_time()

# Create entry widget for text
input = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=5)
input.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

# Start the main loop of the application

app = TimeWgt()
app.update_date_time 
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the OP desired something that looked nice in addition to fixing the variable, here is functional code based on the Class structure suggested by @luisch444 and @JRiggles. It tidies up things further by removing the need for a self.root attribute and removes the separate call to tk.Tk() by having TimeWgt() inherit the tk.Tk() Class.

While general flexibility comes with naming tk.Labels, in this case, separate configurations of the date_time label can be avoided by assigning a tk.StringVar() control variable to an unnamed label's `textvariable` parameter. Time and date are then updated by setting current values to that control variable.

Substituting place() specifications with a simple grid() does a better job of automatically positioning the date label near the top left corner; pack() also works, but puts the label at top center.

The statement `if __name__ == "__main__"` was used to further tidy things up; the block of code under it is run only when the script is executed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime as dt

class TimeWgt(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # Use super() to access the inherited tk.Tk() Class.
        super().__init__()

        self.current_dt = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(textvariable=self.current_dt,
                 font=('Times New Roman', 14),
                 bg='light blue').grid()

        self.update_date_time()

    def update_date_time(self):
        now = dt.now()
        current_date = now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        # Add seconds to show 1 sec updates with after().
        current_time = now.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')

        # Use set() to update Label text with date and time.
        self.current_dt.set(f'{current_date}\n {current_time}')

        self.after(1000, self.update_date_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TimeWgt() instantiates as 'app' (or 'root') and inherits
    #   the tk.Tk class, thus creating the main tk window.
    app = TimeWgt()
    app.title('My App')
    app.geometry('800x600')
    app.configure(bg='light blue')
    app.mainloop()
```